# Ordering dates in R with lubridate

Tags: r, lubridate

I have the following data frame and want to order it.

```
time <- c ("Feb (2019)", "Apr (2019)", "Jun (2019)" ,"Aug (2019)", "Oct (2019)", "Dec (2019)", "Feb (2020)" "Apr (2020)", "Jun (2020)", "Aug (2020)", "Oct (2020)", "Dec (2020)", "Jan (2019)", "Mar (2019)", "May (2019)", "Jul (2019)", "Sep (2019)", "Nov (2019)", "Jan (2020)", "Mar (2020)", "May (2020)", "Jul (2020)" "Sep (2020)", "Nov (2020)", "Jan (2021)")
```

To do this I use the following Code

```
library(lubridate)

time <- gsub("[()]", "", time)
time <- (my(time))
time <- as.data.frame(as.integer(gsub("[-]", "", time)))
arrange(time)
```

Unfortunately, I don't get the result I want:

```
1                           20190201
2                           20190401
3                           20190601
4                           20190801
5                           20191001
6                           20191201
7                           20200201
8                           20200401
9                           20200601
10                          20200801
11                          20201001
12                          20201201
13                          20190101
14                          20190301
15                          20190501
16                          20190701
17                          20190901
18                          20191101
19                          20200101
20                          20200301
21                          20200501
22                          20200701
23                          20200901
24                          20201101
25                          20210101
```

I tried various methods and nothing works. I would appreciate your advice!

Comment: `sort(strptime(sprintf("01 %s",time), "%d %b (%Y)"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reorder the dates as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

time <- c("Feb (2019)", "Apr (2019)", "Jun (2019)", "Aug (2019)", "Oct (2019)", 
          "Dec (2019)", "Feb (2020)", "Apr (2020)", "Jun (2020)", "Aug (2020)", 
          "Oct (2020)", "Dec (2020)", "Jan (2019)", "Mar (2019)", "May (2019)", 
          "Jul (2019)", "Sep (2019)", "Nov (2019)", "Jan (2020)", "Mar (2020)", 
          "May (2020)", "Jul (2020)", "Sep (2020)", "Nov (2020)", "Jan (2021)")

tibble(time = time) %>% 
  arrange(parse_date(time, "%b (%Y)"))
#> # A tibble: 25 x 1
#>    time      
#>    <chr>     
#>  1 Jan (2019)
#>  2 Feb (2019)
#>  3 Mar (2019)
#>  4 Apr (2019)
#>  5 May (2019)
#>  6 Jun (2019)
#>  7 Jul (2019)
#>  8 Aug (2019)
#>  9 Sep (2019)
#> 10 Oct (2019)
#> # ... with 15 more rows
```

If you want to keep the parsed times you can use a call to `mutate()`, e.g.

```
tibble(time = time) %>% 
  mutate(parsed_time = parse_date(time, "%b (%Y)"))
  arrange(parsed_time)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `zoo::as.yearmon`

```
time[order(zoo::as.yearmon(time, '%b (%Y)'))]

# [1] "Jan (2019)" "Feb (2019)" "Mar (2019)" "Apr (2019)" "May (2019)" "Jun (2019)"
# [7] "Jul (2019)" "Aug (2019)" "Sep (2019)" "Oct (2019)" "Nov (2019)" "Dec (2019)"
#[13] "Jan (2020)" "Feb (2020)" "Mar (2020)" "Apr (2020)" "May (2020)" "Jun (2020)"
#[19] "Jul (2020)" "Aug (2020)" "Sep (2020)" "Oct (2020)" "Nov (2020)" "Dec (2020)"
#[25] "Jan (2021)"
```